# Maven cxf-xjc-plugin xpath not working as expected inside bindings file

Tags: java, xpath, jaxb

Ok here we go. I have simple example here with just couple of lines for simplicity but it still does not work. XPath testing in web browser finds the element as expected.

plugin in pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <fork>true</fork>
                        <additionalJvmArgs>-Djdk.xml.maxOccurLimit=99999999</additionalJvmArgs>
                        <additionalJvmArgs>-verbose</additionalJvmArgs>
                        <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                        <xsdOptions>
                            <xsdOption>
                                <extension>true</extension>
                                <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsds/CC015C.xsd</xsd>
                                <bindingFiles>
                                    <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsds/CC015C_bindings.xjb</bindingFile>
                                </bindingFiles>
                                <packagename>generated.messages</packagename>
                            </xsdOption>
                        </xsdOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                    <extensions>
                        <extension>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins:cxf-xjc-dv:3.3.1</extension>
                    </extensions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

CC015C.xsd content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
    targetNamespace="http://example.eu"
    elementFormDefault="unqualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    version="51.40"
    vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <complexType name="CC015CType">
  </complexType>
</schema>
```

CC015C_bindings.xjb (CCType is just some class that I have and should be extended by CC015CType):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    jaxb:version="2.1"
>
  <annotation>
    <appinfo>
        <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="*">
            <jaxb:bindings node="//complexType[@name='CC015CType']">
                <xjc:superClass name="com.example.demo.model.CCType" />
            </jaxb:bindings>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </appinfo>
  </annotation>
</schema>
```

When I run this, I get this exception:

```
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; Failed to create model
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error(ErrorReceiver.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.XSDToJavaRunner.loadModel(XSDToJavaRunner.java:226)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.XSDToJavaRunner.run(XSDToJavaRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.XSDToJavaRunner.main(XSDToJavaRunner.java:360)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.XSDToJavaRunner.loadModel(XSDToJavaRunner.java:224)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number: ''http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb''
    at java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(MessageFormat.java:1429)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(MessageFormat.java:479)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(MessageFormat.java:362)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:840)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Messages.format(Messages.java:24)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.buildDOMForest(ModelLoader.java:278)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:318)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:121)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:76)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "''http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb''"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(MessageFormat.java:1427)
    ... 15 more


[ERROR] C:\example\prototype\src\main\resources\xsds\CC015C.xsd [0:0]: Failed to create model
```